# TimestampRangeFilter - all cells returned for row, or just matched cells?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Does the `TimestampRangeFilter` in Bigtable return all cells for returned rows, even if not all cells meet the filter criteria?

Example:

Say I have a row in Bigtable. I wrote a bunch of cells to the row 10 minutes ago. 5 minutes ago, I updated one cell in the row.

If I run a `TimestampRangeFilter` for 5 minutes ago or later, will I get the entire row and all of its cells back, or just the cell that was updated 5 minutes ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I run a `TimestampRangeFilter` for 5 minutes ago or later, will I get the entire row and all of its cells back, or just the cell that was updated 5 minutes ago?

The latter: the objective of the time range filter is to return the values in the range you specified. You can see some examples in [this commit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/commit/7bb67ec9e3e20f50a5968388da7cb58267ebc9d5) which added tests for `TimestampRangeFilter` in the Go client.

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to get the entire row for all rows whose cells have seen updates in the past hour, I would need to first get those row keys with the `TimestampRangeFilter` and then query each row separately?